# Unable to click on button in window using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am new to AHK, and tried to simulate clicking of button on a window.
I want to click on the "Accept" button of the splash window. However it does not work. Below is the WinSpy of the window.
The window is like this :-
[image]

The control "TcxButton2" is highlighted in ClassNN.

I tried the following

```
^j::
;Run, KBDiag.exe , C:\Program Files\Knorr-Bremse\KB Diag
If WinExist "AHK_class TformSplash"
{
    ;WinActivate
    ;PostMessage does not work too
    ;PostMessage, 0x201, , , TcxButton2, Accept ; 0x201 is WM_LBUTTONDOWN
    ;PostMessage, 0x202, , , TcxButton2, Accept ; 0x202 is WM_LBUTTONUP
    ;
    WinActivate
    ControlFocus , TcxButton2, Knorr-Bremse SfN,, , 
    ControlClick , TcxButton2, Knorr-Bremse SfN,, , 
    MsgBox %ErrorLevel%  ; ErrorLevel is '1' , hence something was not okay


}

Return
```

See screenshot of the splash window below
[image]

I dont know what I am doing wrong.
Help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve this.
The property SetTitleMatchMode must be set to '2' if the string to be matched can be present anywhere in the window.

As seen in AHK help file :-

```
  SetTitleMatchMode, MatchMode

  2: A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.
```

Working code here :-

```
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    ControlSendButton = TcxButton2
    ControlFocus , %ControlSendButton%, ,Knorr-Bremse SfN, ,
    ; Also the string is not present in WinTitle, hence the string is matched against WinText now
    ControlClick , %ControlSendButton%, ,Knorr-Bremse SfN, ,
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `controlFocus` here, do you? also, I might be wrong but `WinActivate` is unneccessary, too, for it would only activate the one window which is foremost already

Comment: WinActivate and ControlFocus might be not necessary, you are right, but I think adding these 2 lines makes it sure that the splash window will be clicked always. No harm I guess :)